# Dynamic Column css Based On Window Size AngularJs

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, meanjs

This may be answered somewhere, but I am unsure of exact terminology as I am new to web development. I am working with a mean.js app and I have a a container that I am filling:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
     <div class="panel" ng-repeat='item in itemList'>
      {{item.content}}
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I don't actually want the col sizes to be as specified there. I would like to set the panel sizes to a set size, something like 150px X 150px per panel and I want the rows to fill with columns based on the resolution of the screen. So if the column hits the end of the screen I want it to start a new row only in that case. For example, if I had 10 panels and someone had a window 1500px wide it would only show 1 row, but as they shrunk the window it would readjust until eventually only showing 1 panel per row.

Hopefully this is something that is possible, but any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `display:inline-block` for those inner boxes.
This will ensure that, the boxes will take all the available space on a row, 
After that, it will go to the next row

```css
.c-panel {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="c-panel"></div>
  <div class="c-panel"></div>
  <div class="c-panel"></div>
  <div class="c-panel"></div>
  <div class="c-panel"></div>
  <div class="c-panel"></div>
  <div class="c-panel"></div>
  <div class="c-panel"></div>
  <div class="c-panel"></div>
  <div class="c-panel"></div>
  <div class="c-panel"></div>
  <div>
```

Comment: Hi, I gave this a try. It doesnt seem to be working. I am using bootstrap panels as my boxes, so I set that css you gave as the css for .panel but it didnt change.

Comment: @Code2Code, try changing class name